# Azure DevOps yaml-pipeline deployment: "Provider phase is not supported"

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-yaml-pipelines

Azure DevOps yaml-pipeline with [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#deployment-job) fails with error `Provider phase is not supported`.

What am I doing wrong?

Azure DevOps Server Version `Dev17.M153.5`.

```
trigger:
- master
jobs:
- deployment: ExperimentalDeploy
  displayName: Deploy my app
  pool: MyPool
  environment: experimental_environment
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo Hello world
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It because [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-2019) is not available in Azure DevOps Server 2019:

[image]

Also in the [YAML page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) when you change to Azure DevOps Server 2019 you couldn't see the deployment job:

[image]

[image]